# Can I allow certain people to add/edit pages within a parent?

Tags: plugins, pages, user-roles

I'm planning on building a site with different sections, for example:

- Training
- Conferences
- Ideas

A different person will be in charge of editing and managing each section. They will be able to edit the parent page and add, edit and delete sub-pages within each section. I don't want each person to be able to add/edit/delete pages from a section that they don't manage.

As far as I can tell if I give each person an "editor" role then they will be able to add/edit/delete pages from each section. If I give them an author role, then they won't be able to add pages at all.

Is there a way to achieve my goal from within Wordpress? If not, will I need to use a plugin, and if so, can you recommend one that will help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Role Scoper: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/

Comment: Thanks for this. I am assuming then that Word Press doesn't have this functionality built in. Role Scoper looks very powerful (and complicated). Unfortunately it seems to be quite buggy on my server and I get quite a few error messages when I change themes etc. However, I think this is the way forwards.

Comment: No, it's not built in to WordPress I'm afraid, and you're right, Role Scoper is pretty confusing! I only used it on one site a couple of years ago so I can't comment about problems with recent versions.